# What does 'back-stopping' mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, word-usage, legalese

We have a tender document, and it lists how the offer should be proposed.  Basically this is split into 3 sections:

1. Rationale
2. Strategy
3. Details of Proposal

Under section 2., there is this clause:

> A description of the support facilities **(back-stopping)** that the
>   contractor and his team will have  during the execution of the
>   contract

What does the phrase 'back-stopping' mean, in this context?  Just for reference, below you can find the entire content of 2. Strategy.

> 2. STRATEGY
>
> - An outline of the approach proposed for contract implementation.
> - A list of the proposed activities considered to be necessary to achieve the contract objectives
> - The related inputs and outputs
> - In the case of a tender being submitted by a consortium, a description of the input from each of the consortium partners and the distribution and interaction of tasks and responsibilities between them
> - A description of the support facilities (back-stopping) that the contractor and his team will have  during the execution of the contract
> - A description of sub-contracting arrangements foreseen, if any and within the limit indicated in clause 3 of the Instructions to tenderers, with a clear indication of the tasks that will be entrusted to a sub-contractor and a statement by the tenderer guaranteeing the eligibility of any sub-contractor

Comment: Also see [pictures of backstops](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1347&bih=788&q=backstop&oq=backstop&gs_l=img.3..0j0i5l5j0i24l4.1344.4711.0.5037.2.2.0.0.0.0.110.207.1j1.2.0...0.0...1ac.1.2.img.QBFYMHM5OoI) that illustrate the usual sense in the U.S. of *backstop*

Comment: I reccomend moving this to ELL.

Comment: Yes, a "back stop" is the fence behind "home plate" in baseball, and it serves to prevent foul balls from flying backwards into the bleachers.  By analogy, anything that stops/deflects/controls errant objects or activities is a "back stop".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> back·stop
>   /ˈbakˌstäp/
>   Noun
>   A person or thing placed at the rear of or behind something as a barrier, support, or reinforcement.
>   Verb
>   Support or reinforce: "the founding banks were backstopping the loans".

Your document pretty much defines it as *support facilities* and then puts this equivalent colloquialism in parentheses.

In this case, they are using a bit of license (not much) with a word that is already a metaphor. They use it to mean that capability that they have to support or back-up (stand behind) their activities in relation to the execution of their responsibilities.

In this case, I would read it as "capabilities to mitigate risk (prevent things from going wrong)," just as the physical backstop keeps the ball on the field, where it can be controlled.

Comment: I learned the term as "bat-stop", as in a fence or net that stops bats after the hitter swings and throws the bat away. If that were the root term, that would make *back-stop* a *back-formation*.

Comment: @AlexChaffee - I've only ever (in the US) heard "back-stop".

Comment: "Back-stop" is correct, not "bat-stop".  It stops wild pitches and foul balls much more often than it stops thrown bats.

Answer (score 1):

The term "backstopping" is used widely in project management and project application prosa, especially in the context of international projects, i.e. where everybody speaks English, but not everybody very well. I suppose that very little of those people who use it know its etymology or initial use-case. When saying "backstopping", people usually mean  "support", often especially "support through some larger unit or office in the background that actually does not much, but at least *could* provide support in case something goes terribly wrong, e.g. find a new project manager or pay for damages.

I have met "backstopping" often in both calls for proposals by the European Union, and project applications written for those programmes.